# "Toggle" navigation with animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm writing a code which will hide my navbar on scroll and display it again accordingly.
So far it works well, but I was curious on how implement some animation or transition to reveal/hide that element.

Here's my code so far

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("bottom-navigation").style.bottom = "0";    
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bottom-navigation").style.bottom = "-100px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use CSS `transform` and `transition` which (in contrast to other properties like `bottom` `top` etc) can be GPU accelerated
- Use a special class like i.e: `.hidden` or `.hide`
  than, all you need in JavaScript is a [**Element.classList.toggle**(*className, boolean*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle that class
- **Never** use *`on(eventname)`*- unless you're creating brand new elements from in-memory.
  `on*` will override any previously added *eventname* to that element. Use a *cumulative* approach instead, by using [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
const EL_bottomNav = document.querySelector("#bottom-navigation");

let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

const toggleBottomNav = () => {
  EL_bottomNav.classList.toggle("hide", prevScrollpos <= window.pageYOffset);
  prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
};

// Do immediately:
// toggleBottomNav();

// And on page scroll:
window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleBottomNav);
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  min-height: 300vh; /* just to force some scrollbars */
}

#bottom-navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  background: gold;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#bottom-navigation.hide {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
Scroll down and than up
<footer id="bottom-navigation">I'm the bottom nav!</footer>
```

*Nota bene:*
Since Events added on scroll are expensive, don't query the DOM for your Element. Cache it beforehand instead (like in the example above). Also a throttle function would be helpful to leverage the load of function calls passed to the event loop in main thread.

Comment: umm is there any other way than css cuz im actually using tailwind, but thanks tho it was helpfull

Comment: @ASTREX https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles - I don't personally use Tailwind, but seems like they have ways to do it.

Comment: Also as a developer to a developer — Tailwind,  is just a really bad idea in the long term.

Comment: do you have any suggestion like about any other frameworks or using pure css, im thinking for something long term thanks

Comment: To give some context to my statement, Tailwind is *nice* to get you started without touching a single line of CSS. First of, HTML should not be bloated with classes. Specially not with the silly ones Tailwind implies. I know you can use apply all over the place, but on a bigger project Tailwind will start to snake-eat itself from the tail to head. Too much abstraction and Docs to learn. Bootstrap was always late 4y with best practices... Hard to tell. I always write my CSS from scratch, you need 40 lines to create a grid system, than use atoms and reuse your own components.